# Xpath scrapy filter the filtered selector

Tags: xpath, scrapy

Is it possible to make something like (using the xpath only):

```
filtered = response.xpath('//input[@type="submit"]')
filtered.xpath('[contains(@name, "abc")]')
```

The above code produces exception:

> ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in [contains(@name,
>   "abc")]

Answer (score 1):

You can either select initially correct elements:

```
filtered = response.xpath('//input[@type="submit"][contains(@name, "abc")]')
```

or filter as below

```
filtered = response.xpath('//input[@type="submit"]')
# by exact @name value
new_filtered = [item for item in filtered if item.attrib['name'] == 'abc']
# by partial @name value
new_filtered = [item for item in filtered if 'abc' in item.attrib['name']]
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion on using `attrib` attribute, but I wonder if it is at all possible to do the same using xpath selector only in second filter.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such functionality in XPath. You can do as `filtered.xpath('./parent::*/input[contains(@name, "abc")]')`, but this is just a workaround